# disable div content error

Tags: css, html, selection

I can disable the content of my div using this

```
<div style='-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
' onselectstart='return false;'>
```

I have two contents inside my div, the first one is the

```
<input>
```

and the other is

```
<textarea>
```

When I drag my mouse, both can't be selected. But when I right click + select all. I can select the content of my textbox, but not the input box.

NOTE: I am using an openWYSIWYG editor for my textarea, I've also tried putting transparent div at top but got same result.

the question is, how can I totally disable the selection?

Comment: So what's your question/problem exactly?

Comment: @Nightfirecat I edited my question, see the bottom part :)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to disable a form element is to set  it's `disabled="disabled"` flag with the help of JavaScript. This method works well.

You can **not** add this attribute for `div` elements, but you can emulate the behaviour of the disabled element by setting the color of selected text the same as the background of `div` using CSS code like

```
::selection {
background: #xxxxxx;
}
::-moz-selection {
background: #xxxxxx;
}
```

where `#xxxxxx` is the `background-color` of the div element.

Comment: I wanted to totally disable the selection

Comment: Setting this flag will totally disable the element.

Comment: There is to add, that this works only on **form fields**. Using this with a `<div>` will result in invalid HTML.

Comment: @insertusernamehere for sure, this flag should be added **ONLY** to form fields. To these ones which are needed to be disabled.

Comment: Oh, I was totally focussed on that `<div>` in the question. But when using a WYSIWYG-editor the textarea will most likely be replaced with a `<div>` or even an `<iframe>` (with tinyMCE) which will not inherit the `disabled`-attribute/behavior.

Comment: Hm, what you did in your edit is: make it look like it was disabled. What the OP actually wants (I guess) is that the user cannot select the text, which is still possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard behavior on the CSS `user-select`-attribute. So in Safari the the "select all" option or just selecting surrounding elements will still select the content in-between – as you've experienced.

Here are some more information: "[css-tricks.com: User-Select](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/)"

Note, that this CSS does not prevent users from viewing the source of the page and copy the content from there. As stated by Chris it's more for the purpose to not select content accidentally.